# Powershell Converting String to Integer

Tags: string, powershell, type-conversion, integer

This is similar to my last question, however with a small change.
Once again I cannot seem to overcome the conversion.

```
$myVar = "4MB"
$myVarInt = ([convert]::ToInt32($myVar, 10))*1MB

$myVarInt
```

Gives Error: Exception calling "ToInt32" with "2" argument(s): "Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string."

I assume this is the quotes on the $myVar causing issue.
How can I get this to work?

Comment: What does `$myvar` contain?

Comment: Without knowing `$myvar`, I’d try `[int]($myvar -replace '\D')*1MB`

Comment: Sorry, updated post. The top line was cut off. @AdminOfThings thank you, that was it! Wow you're good.

Answer (score 0):

There is a string containing characters inside the $myVar variable. It should not matter if the string contains only numbers, but if it contains any characters, that error would be thrown out.

```
# This works
$myVar = "10"
$myVarInt = ([convert]::ToInt32($myVar, 10))*1MB
$myVarInt    
> 10485760

# This does not work
$myVar = "10t"
$myVarInt = ([convert]::ToInt32($myVar, 10))*1MB
Exception calling "ToInt32" with "2" argument(s): "Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string."
At line:1 char:1
+ $myVarInt = ([convert]::ToInt32($myVar, 10))*1MB
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
$myVarInt = [int]($myVar -replace '\D')*1MB
```

If a string contains a mix of digits and non-digits, you can regex match a non-digit with `\D`. The `-replace` operator is used to replace regex matched characters with another string. The combination of `-replace '\D'` will replace all non-digits with an empty string regardless of their position within the string.

The `[int]` cast will by default attempt a conversion to `Int32`.